# System.Reflection: Storing Expression for Later Use

Tags: c#, generics, system.reflection

So, I using MVC and I am using a JS library called DataTable to display data. Well, I am feeding the data to the table using an AJAX response from the server. Because I'll be using DataTable a lot, I decided to create a model that allows me to quickly create an instance and feed back the data to the client. I have all this worked out, however, I have one issue with searching. I am using `Expression.Call()` to build a query at RunTime for my data to be collected from my database. I am working with generics because I have many different models I am displaying with DataTable and this was created to minimize my line of code.

Well, sometime the calls will take about a second to complete and return back to the client. Not terrible, but I believe there should be a way to improve this time. I thought about storing the method that I generated in from `Expression.Call()` in a variable and call it later. The only issue is my variable is not defined once I used the cached Expression. I have to feed my methods a parameter at the beginning and this is causing the issue.

Also, I am rather new to using System.Reflection and generics. If there is a better approach to use, please link to the article(s).

The error is something about the variable 'item' exists but is not defined in this context.

```
private static readonly var CachedSearchQuery = new Dictionary<string, MethodCallExpression>();
private Expression<Func<T, bool>> GenerateSearchValues()
            {
                if (search == null || search.value == null)
                    return null;
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> body = null;
            ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
            columns.ForEach(c =>
            {
                if (c.searchable)
                {
                    var prop = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, c.data);
                    var containMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
                    var toLowerMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", Type.EmptyTypes);
                    var toString = typeof(string).GetMethod("ToString", Type.EmptyTypes);

                    var cont = Expression.Constant(search.value, typeof(string));
                    Expression<Func<T, bool>> containExpr = null;

                    if(!CachedSearchQuery.Contains(c.data)) {
                        try
                        {
                            CachedSearchQuery[c.data] = Expression.Call(prop, toLowerMethod);
                            containExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>> (
                                Expression.Call(
                                    CachedSearchQuery[c.data],
                                    containMethod,
                                    cont),
                                param);
                        }
                        catch/*(ArgumentException e)*/
                        {
                            toString = typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString", Type.EmptyTypes);
                            CachedSearchQuery[c.data] = 
                                        Expression.Call(
                                            Expression.Call(prop, toLowerMethod),
                                        toString);
                            containExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
                                Expression.Call(
                                    CachedSearchQuery[c.data],
                                        containMethod,
                                        cont),
                                    param);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        containExpr = 
                            Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
                                Expression.Call(
                                    CachedSearchQuery[c.data],
                                        containMethod,
                                        cont),
                                    param);
                    }

                    if (containExpr == null)
                        return;
                    if (body == null)
                        body = containExpr;
                    else
                    {
                        body = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
                        (
                            Expression.Or(
                                body, 
                                Expression.Invoke(
                                    containExpr, 
                                    body.Parameters.Cast<Expression>()
                                )
                            ),
                        body.Parameters);
                    }
                }
            });

            return body;
        }
```

Comment: How are you using this expression tree you are generating? Some ORM like entity framework? Have you profiled you app to see where time is being spent? Is the bottleneck generating the expression trees, or is it executing them? Is the resulting database query execution time the actual issue?

Comment: @DaveM I'm not if I stated this in my post, but this is a stripped down version I am using because my full version is at work. To answer some of your questions, I am using EF6 on an Oracle backend. From all my tests, I can say there is about a slight hang when it processes through because the more columns it has to sort, the more building it has to do. I know when datasets a larger as well the database time get longer but this is to be expected.